# Access Page_Load event for All .aspx pages at one place

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, global-asax, httpmodule

I want to access `page_load` event of all .aspx pages at one place.

**Scenario:-**

I have an asp.net web site in WebForms (NOT MVC). It has 70-75 `.aspx` pages.
Now I want to perform some **same** business logic in `page_load` event of all pages.

**My Question:-**

Now How can I access `page_load` of all 75 `.aspx` pages at one place so whenever user request for `form1.aspx` or `form2.aspx` or `form58.aspx` at that time I want to call my common function.

**What I tried till :-**

To achieve above scenario I used **`Application_BeginRequest`** event of `Global.asax` file which will be call for each request. **But** now issue is, this **`Application_BeginRequest`** is also called on `button_click`, on `ajax call` **which I don't want**. I want to call my common function **only when `page_load` event is fired**.

Is there any other way to achieve above scenario using `httpmodule` or `httphandler` - If yes please help me.

Thanks,

Physically call that common function in each an every `page_load` is bad idea. I want it at common place.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a base class and make all your pages inherit it and call some function from base in all the page load.

otherwise you could override the page life cycle event in your base class.

And also check this out for checking whether a request is postback or not in global.asax

[How do I detect if a request is a callback in the Global.asax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110625/how-do-i-detect-if-a-request-is-a-callback-in-the-global-asax)

Answer (score 0):

You might can do it this way:

```
1. create a separate class file Common_Page_Load.cs

2. Write your logic inside that class file Common_Page_Load.cs

3. Call that class file in every page_load function:
   form1.aspx or form2.aspx or form58.aspx.

4. If that needs to be conditional,
   then create a Session variable and you might use it accordingly.
```

for example:

```
    class Common_Page_Load { // separate .cs file

    public bool some_logic() {
     ...
    if(...){
       return true;}
    else{
       return false;}
    }
}

Page_Load(...) { //page load of form 1 or form 2 or form 50 or so

    if(Session["check_logic"] == "true"){
       Common_Page_Load  CP = new CP();
       bool myvar = CP.some_logic();
       ...
       ...
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is not the solution ... you have to call that function in each and 70-75 .aspx pages ... - See my question - I want central place